# How to create a formula for every row in a column in Google SpreadSheet?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, worksheet-function, formulas

I use three columns. "H", "O" and "I". In column "I", I have a formula every row =IF( OR( O3 = "Yes",H3 = "Yes"),"Yes","No") and then for the next row I have =IF( OR( O4 = "Yes",H4 = "Yes"),"Yes","No").

How do I copy the formula for the new rows being added to the worksheet without having to write any code behind? i.e. purely using formulas.
e.g. for arithmetic operations I can use something similar to below.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E,E3:E*F3:F,0))

Can I use a similar approach for here as well?  if Yes, How do I exactly use it for my case?

I'm using Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use OR in Arrayformula you'll need to use +.
Can you see if this works ?

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(H4:H), IF((O4:O = "Yes")+(H4:H = "Yes"),"Yes","No"),))
```

Comment: it doesn't work as expected. Please check the demo below.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rc8oB_ozY-pLKN5pxYqgKCGiXdFKvWEzoBVO72hT-vw/edit#gid=0

Comment: I'm not sure. in real case I have more conditions in the formula. e.g. =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(H3:H), IF((O3:O = "Yes")+(H3:H = "Yes")+(J3:J >= 0.1)+(K3:K >=0.2)+(L3:L >=0.5)+(N3:N>=0.5)+(M3:M>=0.5),"Yes","No"),"No")) if one of those conditions are true, I'm expecting corresponding I column to print "Yes" else "No". e.g. In the demo I have 50% on the L7 and the expected value for I7 is "Yes" but it is still "No". am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi ecasper, try converting the column with the percent values to pure number first.. |
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(H4:H), IF((O4:O = "Yes")+(H4:H = "Yes")+(J4:J >= 0.1)+(K4:K >=0.2)+(to_pure_number(L4:L) >=0.5)+(N4:N>=0.5)+(M4:M>=0.5),"Yes","No"),)) Please note that this will limit the output in Col I to only those cells that have values in col H.